# developing application for different symbian devices

Tags: qt, sdk, symbian

I need to develop applications for nokia devices running `S60 3rd Edition, Feature Pack 1, S60 3rd Edition, Feature Pack 2 S60 5th Edition, Symbian^3` the documentations in nokia forums is not quite understandable. I understand that at present to develop applications for nokia device `qt` to be used. Now there are two versions of [qt SDK 1.1.4](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html) and [qt SDK 1.1.2](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/84801bfe-8517-4287-9829-014c6f572127/Qt_SDK_1_1_2.html)

Which should i download to develop applications for the all the three symbian platforms..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should stick to 1.1.2.

Qt SDK 1.1.4 contains only the latest targets for developing applications for a particular Symbian platform. The targets for Qt 4.6.3 for Symbian and Qt 4.7.3 for Symbian^3 and Symbian Anna have been removed from Qt SDK 1.1.4. To develop for these targets, use Qt SDK 1.1.2. Once you have installed Qt SDK 1.1.2, to enable use of the earlier targets and App TRK, don’t run the SDK update as this will remove the features you need.